# Unable to run C++ cmake project in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, version, clion

I have extracted the files from a Zip file for a C++ project, in order to run it in CLion.
However, when I try to build the project I am receiving the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" "C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Saxion\Year 1_redo\C++ foundations\Exam"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.19 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.17.3


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[Finished]
```

When running the `cmake --version` command in command prompt it states other wise:

```
cmake version 3.21.0-rc1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Contents of the CmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Exam)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

How can I envoke the Clion to use the correct version of CMake.

Comment: Looks like you have two different versions of `cmake` installed on your machine, in different locations.

Comment: @PaulSanders Which is the correct version and how can I change it in CLion? Thanks in advance

Comment: That I don't know, sorry, I don't use CLion, but if you search your machine for all copies of `cmake.exe`, you might learn more.